# Azure storage Blobs GetBlobs method failing despite correct container, correct path and uri

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure.Storage.Blobs ver 12.14... for this, as the older SDK's are being deprecated and our storage service code needs to be updated.

The following code, which matches the Microsoft docs tutorial, is failing but NOT causing an exception. It just falls thru to the caller and results in an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

Here is one method (updated based on Guarav's suggestions below)

```
public async Task<List<EvaluationImage>> GetImagesFromVirtualFolder(CompanyDataDto? customer)
{
    var images = new List<EvaluationImage>();
    var imageFolderPrefix = $"publicfiles/images/{customer.AzureFolderName}/";
    var containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(ConnectionSettings.PrimaryConnection,
       ContainerSettings.MainAppContainer);

    try
    {
        await foreach (var blob in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: imageFolderPrefix))
        {
            var filename = blob.Name;
            var img = new EvaluationImage
            {
                ImageUrl = $"{containerClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri}/{filename}",
                ImageCaption = GetCaptionFromFilename(filename),
                IsPosterImage = filename.Contains("poster"),
                ImagesForCompany = customer.CompanyName
            };
        }
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException ex)
    {
        Log.Logger.Error(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }

    return images;
}
```

While the code is in the foreach loop, it exits before any iterating is done. It falls to the caller (razor page code behind) and then the error occurs in the page where I am iterating through the collection to build the image tags.

That method produces a valid container

[image: container as text]

You can paste the url below in your browser and it will download.
//https://enerteckchemical.blob.core.windows.net/enerteck/publicfiles/images/robsonpty/RobsonCivil_CatR475_CrawlerDozer.jpg

and the images in that container are retrievable (they are public)

[one test image from the container](https://enerteckchemical.blob.core.windows.net/enerteck/publicfiles/images/robsonpty/RobsonCivil_CatR475_CrawlerDozer.jpg)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make 2 changes to your code:

1. Change the following line of code:

```
var containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(ConnectionSettings.PrimaryConnection,
        $"enerteck/publicfiles/images/{customer.AzureFolderName}/");
```

to

```
var containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(ConnectionSettings.PrimaryConnection,
        "enerteck");
```

because the name of your blob container is `enerteck`. Everything after that is the blob prefix.

2. Add blob prefix to `GetBlobsAsync` call by changing following line of code:

```
await foreach (var blob in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
```

to

```
await foreach (var blob in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: $"publicfiles/images/{customer.AzureFolderName}/"));
```

So that you are fetching blobs from a virtual folder named `publicfiles/images/{customer.AzureFolderName}`.

**UPDATE**

Here's the code I ran which worked just fine:

```
var connectionString =
    "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;";

var containerName = "enerteck";
var prefix = "publicfiles/images/robsonpty/";

var containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString,
    containerName);

await foreach (var blob in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: prefix))
{
    Console.WriteLine(blob.Name);
}
```

Comment: I made those changes, and I believe I had tried that in one of my earlier attempts. The changes you have outlined here produce the same result, while inside the foreach it drops out to the caller, no caught error and no blobs returned. I also tried removing the slash from the end of enerteck/ and I tried removing it from the end of the prefix, all have no effect

Comment: Let me try to run your code against my storage account.

Comment: I posted the code I changed per your suggestions in the original post

Comment: I also ensured the container and blobs are public...Public read access for container and blobs' for blob container 'enerteck'

Comment: I just tried to run your code against my storage account and it worked perfectly fine.  Updated my answer with my code.

Comment: One possible reason I could think of is the value of `customer.AzureFolderName`. Can you please check if proper value is being passed there.

Comment: I tried it hardcoded as well, same result

Comment: Hmmm....that's weird. Can you create a separate console app and use my code there and see if you are able to see the blob names getting printed properly?

Comment: Well, you are right it works in the console app, but not in the web project I'm working on

Comment: I moved where the code was doing the azure work, and I got it to work. something in the calling pipeline was causing the problem.